# Wifi connection cutting off every 20 minutes

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-router, internet-connection

My internet is turning itself off about every 20 minutes, and I have to go to the network and sharing center and run troubleshoot wifi connection 3 a several times before it goes back to normal.

What I've checked:

- The internet works without fail on my phone. The problem is surely on this device.
- The wifi connection 3 thing on network and sharing center is the thing that always goes offline (has a red cross next to it)
- My intelligence... I'm pretty bad at computing so please explain this in steps.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me how to stop this inconvenience from occurring every 10-20 minutes, its really frustrating. I need to answer questions and get more reputation on writers SE :).

Thanks. By the way, I ran a scan. Its not a virus or malware, whatever else it could be.

Comment: You need first to tell us where the error is occurring: are you losing the wireless link to the router, or is the router losing internet access? The network icon in the system tray will tell you which.

Comment: I am losing the wireless link to the router @AFH

Comment: In that case you need to look at your wireless environment (Control Panel -> Network -> WiFi -> Status). If you have fewer than two bars you're likely to get interference and breaks, though manual intervention should not be required to restore service. To improve the signal, you can move the router, move the PC or install either a better WiFi interface in the PC or  a WiFi extender, which can relay the WiFi signal using Ethernet, mains power or the existing signal. If the PC is a laptop, you should first try moving it, as it's easy to do. If this cures the problem, look at the other solutions.

Comment: I have 4 out of 5 bars. I installed a wifi-booster to the room nearby to help the signal go to the upstairs of my house, so I have no problems there.

Comment: That's very puzzling: can you check the received signal at the repeater (assuming it's the air-to-air type)? Just because you have a good signal to the repeater, doesn't mean the repeater has a good connection to the router. Can you tell if the mobile connects to the extender or to the router when it has continuity while the PC is off-line?

Comment: How do I check that? I am able to connect with a phone 100% of the time to the extender easily, even while the PC is offline

Comment: The extender's HTTP interface should tell you the router's signal strength: if not the only measure is to turn it off and use your 'phone at the same location. However, continuous service on your 'phone through the extender implies that the router's signal must be adequate there. More and more it looks like a problem with the PC's WiFi interface. If it's a driver problem, check if it's from Microsoft and if so look for another from the PC or interface manufacturer. Another test is to run an Ubuntu LiveCD or similar and browse for an hour: disruptions will indicate a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to Uninstall the wifi driver and reinstall
2. Maybe is hardware malfunction, need to replace the wifi card

Comment: Could you make this more clear?